# Issue with Kwargs Color argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I've got an issue when triying to plot histogram of the features from a dataset I'm using. I searched a lot on the internet to find how to fix it but I couldn't. If anyone got an idea I'm interested !

```
dataset_base = pd.read_csv(path_dataset_real, names=names,  skiprows=1, delimiter=';')
dataset_base = pd.DataFrame(dataset_base)
dataset_base['address'] = dataset_base['address'].apply(hexToint)
dataset_refl = dataset_base.loc[dataset_base['Res4H'] == 1]
dataset_true = dataset_base.loc[dataset_base['Res4H'] == 0]
dataset_true = dataset_true.loc[0:571,:]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(10,20))
refl = dataset_refl
true = dataset_true

ax = axes.ravel()

for i in range(0,12):
    _, bins = np.histogram(dataset_base.values[:,i], bins=50)
    ax[i].hist(refl.values[:,i], bins=bins, color='red', alpha=.5)
    ax[i].hist(true.values[:,i], bins=bins, color='green', alpha=.5)
    ax[i].set_title(names[i])
    ax[i].set_yticks(())
ax[0].set_xlabel("Feature Magnitude")
ax[0].set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax[0].legend(["Refls", "Plots"], loc='best')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello, please describe error which you encountered.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/...n.py", line 38, in <module>
    ax[i].hist(refl.values[:,i], bins=bins, color='c', alpha=.5)
  File "C:\Program Files...", line 1703, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files...\_axes.py", line 6187, in hist
    raise ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")
ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset

Comment: To receive help, you need to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is, provide mockup data and code that one can copy&paste and produces the same error. As it stand, it will be difficult to tell you what is the problem because we dont know what is in the dataframes `refl` and `true`

Comment: I cant show you the content of these dataframes, but it's only columns of numbers (float).

Comment: ... which means you can create such dataframe with columns of numbers in your code and update the question with it such that it becomes a [mcve]. Or what would prevent you from doing so?